# R dbWriteTable to Cloud Spanner requiring column names

Tags: r, jdbc, dbi, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to insert data into a Cloud Spanner table using DBI's dbWriteTable in R, however, it is asking me to supply column names. It is my understanding that as long as the dataframe contains the same amount of columns as required by the table then this should work. Here's my code and error I'm facing (leaving out connection details):

Code:

```
write.to.spanner <- function(table, df){
  dbWriteTable(con, table, df, overwrite=FALSE, append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
}

req_df <- data.frame(req_id=123, req_name="test req")

write.to.spanner("dbi_test", req_df)
```

DDL for spanner table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbi_test (
  req_id INT64,
  req_name STRING(20),
) PRIMARY KEY(req_id);
```

Error:

```
Warning: Error in .local: execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate ([Simba][SpannerJDBCDriver](100605) There was an error while executing the DML query : INVALID_ARGUMENT: com.simba.cloudspanner.shaded.com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: com.simba.cloudspanner.shaded.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: INSERT must specify a column list [at 1:1]
INSERT INTO dbi_test VALUES(@var1,@var2)
```

I'm able to insert using dbSendUpdate but would prefer to use dbWriteTable and not write out insert statements.

This works fine:

```
write.to.spanner <- function(table, df){
  insert_qry <- paste0("INSERT INTO ",table," (req_id, req_name) VALUES (",df[1,1],",'",df[1,2],"');")
  dbSendUpdate(con,insert_qry)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the column names are needed in the statement by the GoogleSQL (maybe not if you use PostgresSQL dialect when creating the db). Have you tried hacking this by putting the column names in the table name? Changing the dialect is also something you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud spanner has two different kind of dialect, If you are using GoogleSQL, the column name list in the syntax are required: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert-statement

```
INSERT [INTO] table_name
 (column_name_1 [, ..., column_name_n] )
 input [return_clause]
```

I think that is what dialect you are using. But if you can try PostgreSQL dialect which is PG syntax, dbWriteTable could work because column name list in PG is not required. Note: It seems your code also using Simba as the JDBC driver, you also need switch to Spanner JDBC Driver, because Simba does not support the new/PostgreSQL dialect.